# How can I remove the battery from my Samsung P1000?

Tags: battery, samsung-galaxy-tab

My P1000 tablet needs rebooting but will not respond to any input commands.
If I remove the battery I believe this will force the tablet to reboot.

How do I get to the battery?

Comment: I don't think the Galaxy Tabs are really designed for the battery to be removed. Not without a fair amount of work, anyway. [Here's a teardown for the 7" Tab](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Samsung-Galaxy-Tab-Teardown/4103/1), for example.

Comment: This isn't an Android question, it is a hardware question.  You need to talk to the manufacturer or the retailer.

Comment: Does the tablet not have a way to hard reset the device? For example, on my xoom, It's a combination of VOL UP + Power button that will restart the tablet.

Comment: @Logos It's specific to an Android device, which makes it an Android question.

Comment: Last time I looked at the question, the bits about not responding to input commands weren't very clear.  Looks like Eldareathis cleaned it up.

Answer (score 2):

Like it was pointed out, the `Galaxy Tab` wasn't designed in a way for it's battery to be easily removed. Here's a video on removing the case and exploring what's inside. Hope this helps.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=urGUKerJOhg